# How to make a reusable modifier for view lifecycle events (onAppear, onDisappear)?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a common `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` animation that I use for when views appear and disappear:

```
struct ActiveView: View {
    @State var showCode: Bool = false
    @State var opacity = 0.0
    var body: some View {

    if self.showCode {
        Color.black.opacity(0.7)
            .onAppear{
                let animation = Animation.easeIn(duration: 0.5)
                    return withAnimation(animation) {
                        self.opacity = 1
                    }
            }
            .onDisappear{
                let animation = Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.5)
                    return withAnimation(animation) {
                        self.opacity = 0
                    }
            }
    }
    }
}
```

However, I want to use these same animations on other views, so I want it to be simple and reusable, like this:

```
if self.showCode {
    Color.black.opacity(0.7)
        .fadeAnimation()
}
```

How can I achieve this?

EDIT:

Trying to implement a View extension:

```
extension View {
    func fadeAnimation(opacity: Binding<Double>) -> some View {
        self.onAppear{
            let animation = Animation.easeIn(duration: 0.5)
                return withAnimation(animation) {
                    opacity = 1
                }
        }
        .onDisappear{
            let animation = Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.5)
                return withAnimation(animation) {
                    opacity = 0
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a view extension to achieve the same functionality as well as reusable for each view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you try to do is already present and named *opacity transition*, which is written in one modifier.

Here is a demo:

[image: demo]

```
struct ActiveView: View {
    @State var showCode: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if self.showCode {
                Color.black.opacity(0.7)
                    .transition(AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.default))
            }
            Button("Demo") { self.showCode.toggle() }
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The functionality that you are trying to implement is already part of the Animation and Transition modifiers from SwiftUI.

Therefore, you can add `.transition` modifier to any of your `Views` and it will animate its insertion and removal.

```
if self.showCode {
    Color.black.opacity(0.7)
        .transition(AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5)))
}
```

You can use a multitude of different transitions like `.slide`, `.scale`, `.offset`, etc. More information about transitions [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/anytransition).

You can even create custom transitions with different actions for insertion and removal. In your case, different animation curves.

```
extension AnyTransition {
    static var fadeTransition: AnyTransition {
        .asymmetric(
            insertion: AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.easeIn(duration: 0.5)),
            removal: AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5))
        )
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
if self.showCode {
    Color.black.opacity(0.7)
        .transition(.fadeTransition)
}
```

Hope this helps !